# Why can't I install Ubuntu from Live USB?

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb, ubuntu-netbook, cd-image

I have been using Ubuntu and other distro's for years, but I have never had such difficulty trying to install it for a friend.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 from Live USB to an *HP Mini 210-1036VU* netbook but I am getting faulty medium errors. I have tried another  USB drive, alternate install, using USB creator and Unetbootin from two different computers and different release image versions (12.04.01, 12.04.02 etc) & all to the same end!
On the HP Mini the disk check boot mode gives one error. It's clean on my own laptop and image checksums are matched.
Should I try booting from an external disk drive? Is there possibly some discreet limitation to booting from a USB drive on this computer? Hardware drivers? I haven't found the same problem in forums yet.
I'll try to provide more data on request.

Comment: Do you get a error message, and what does it state exactly? And which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install (32 or 64 bit?)

Comment: First, just to make sure you are using the latest Unetbootin and not older versions. personally I don't unetbootin. I use rufus (http://rufus.akeo.ie/) cuz it's faster and seems like a better tool. Sometimes these tools need custom-scripts written for the installation of newer linux iso image because not all iso image are created equal. Can you boot up (not install) that live-usb drive on a regular desktop? btw, sometimes you can install a linux distro onto a computer with a bootable usb image but you cannot boot up its live-usb image to test run it because live-usb has a different setup scrip

Answer (score 0):

I've been just as frustrated as you before, and as it turns out, I had failed to check **BIOS**.

You ***didn't mention*** you've checked BIOS, so maybe checked that?

- Booting order/sequence on BIOS is important, USB must be on top.
- Also make sure that `Allow booting from usb` is checked.
- Also unplugged any other usb device that may be interfering.

I hope this was useful :-)